# Is it possible to break and resume in a reversed list (like etaremune)?

Tags: numbering, lists, etaremune

I am trying to find a way to break and resume using a reversed list.

It seems that the environment `etaremune` and the option `resume` are not compatible.

Is there something I can do?

Thanks.

Comment: The `resume` key is not available for `etaremune`, but for `enumitem`, which in turn can't be reversed, as far as I know

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this out of the box as far as I know, but it can be achieved with a little tinkering.

Below is an implementation of a `resume` key for the `etaremune` environment that mimicks the behaviour of the same key from the `enumitem` package.
Modifying `enumitem` to count backwards should also be possible, but would likely require a lot more effort.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\usepackage{etoolbox} %% For \AtEndEnvironment

\makeatletter %% <- change @ so that it can be used in macro names
  %% Define the resume key for etaremune:
  \define@boolkey[EM]{etaremune}{resume}[true]{}
  \presetkeys[EM]{etaremune}{resume=false}{} %% <- false by default

  %% Increase starting value of previous etaremune environment if resuming
  \AtEndEnvironment{etaremune}{%
    \ifEM@etaremune@resume
      \EM@resumewrite{\csname EM@prevlist@\@roman{\@enumdepth}\endcsname}{\EM@currlist}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\xdef\csname EM@prevlist@\@roman{\@enumdepth}\endcsname{\EM@currlist}%
  }
  \newcommand*\EM@resumewrite[2]{% %% Expand arguments and then call EM@resume@write@
    \begingroup
      \edef\temp{\noexpand\EM@resumewrite@
        {\expandafter\string\csname etaremune@#1\endcsname}%
        {\expandafter\string\csname etaremune@#2\endcsname}}%
      \temp
    \endgroup
  }
  \newcommand*\EM@resumewrite@[2]{% %% Write to aux file
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\xdef#1{\string\noexpand\string\the\numexpr#1+\string\noexpand#2 }}%
  }
\makeatother %% <- change @ back

\begin{document}

\begin{etaremune}
\item Some words \item More words
\end{etaremune}

Interruption

\begin{etaremune}[resume]
\item
    Some words
\item
    More words
    \begin{etaremune}
    \item Some words \item More words
    \end{etaremune}
    Interruption
    \begin{etaremune}[resume]
    \item Some words \item More words
    \end{etaremune}
\end{etaremune}

Interruption

\begin{etaremune}[resume]
\item Some words \item More words \item Final words
\end{etaremune}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### How this works:

The `etaremune` package writes the starting value for each `etaremune` environment to the aux file.
The value for the `<n>`-th environment is stored in the macro `\etaremune@<n>` (with `<n>` formatted as a roman number).
At the start of every `etaremune` environment, the enumeration counter is set to this value (plus one, because it will be decremented).

The only thing we thus have to do is modify the value of `\etaremune@<m>` whenever the next `etaremune` environment at the same depth has a `resume` key.
Getting this to work (in two runs) when there are multiple breaks was a little bit tricky though.
What I do is write

```
\xdef \etaremune@<m>{\noexpand\the\numexpr \etaremune@<m>+\noexpand\etaremune@<n> }
```

to the aux file whenever the `<n>`-th `etaremune` environment is resuming the `<m>`-th.
This sets `\etaremune@<m>` equal to the sum of its original value and the value of `\etaremune@<n>`.
The `\noexpand`s are there so that the value of `\etaremune@f<m>` will be affected if `\etaremune@<n>` is changed later on (due to the presence of another `resume` below it).